# Sort a spread sheet via gspread

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, gspread

I have a Google spreadsheet full of names,  dates, and some other numbers.
I made an desktop application that provides a nice UI for said info.
After using the application a bit I became slightly annoyed with the order the data was being displayed.

I have been researching all day and I cannot seem to find anything on the topic of sorting the spreadsheet from a python script.
All I need is some function that I can call every time someone adds something to it to re-sort the sheet.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible w/ gspread ([Feature Request](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/330)), but was added to the [sheets v4 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/data#sort_a_range_with_multiple_sorting_specifications).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GSpread has a `.sort()` method to sort a worksheet using given sort orders. Here's how you can use it (Source - [GSpread Docs](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html)):

Parameters:

- specs (list) – The sort order per column. Each sort order represented by a tuple where the first element is a column index and the second element is the order itself: ‘asc’ or ‘des’.
- range (str) – The range to sort in A1 notation. By default sorts the whole sheet excluding frozen rows.

Example:

```
# Sort sheet A -> Z by column 'B'
wks.sort((2, 'asc'))

# Sort range A2:G8 basing on column 'G' A -> Z
# and column 'B' Z -> A
wks.sort((7, 'asc'), (2, 'des'), range='A2:G8')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PyGsheets](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) lib. It uses sheets API v4 on lower level.

[`my_worksheet.sort_range()`](http://sort_range()) function will help you but it has some specialities

1. Numbering in `start` and `end` cells start with 1 but
   `basecolumnindex` starts with 0.
2. You can pass the cell's address in 2 ways: text index (like `"A3"`)  or tuple with 2 elements (like `(1, 3)`). The second way doesn't work for me.
3. The range limited by `start` and `end` cells should contain column passed in `basecolumnindex`